# How to create custom TFS check-in policies in .NET Core 2.0?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0, checkin-policy

I'm familiar with the new deployment/installation design of VS 2017, and the way it leaves no footprint on registry.

And I'm also familiar with how we need to change our check-in policy installation [from registry manipulation to VS extension creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923272/custom-tfs-check-in-policy-in-visual-studio-2017).

However, now I need to create check-in policies in .NET Core 2.0. The problem is that I need to use `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client` dll to be able to access `PolicyBase` and also `PendingChange` classes. This results in `FileNotFoundException`.

Also I need to use `Mono.Cecil` as the reflection library, to be able to process things in more detail before checking-in. I can't find if `Mono.Cecil` supports .NET Core 2.0 or not. Nuget page is not informative and the libraries page on GitHub is also not easy to understand.

And another obstacle is to create a VS Extension. I can't find out the required package definition items to be added to source control.

Can you please provide a simple example of how to create a custom TFS Check-in Policy in VS 2017 via .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: Why you have to create the check-in policy project with .Net Core 2.0?  For now the TFS .NET client libraries packages, some of the dependencies are not compatible with .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the policy ends up running in the context of Visual Studio itself, I believe you have to be compatible with the .NET framework that Visual Studio is running in, and that is the "classic" .NET Framework, not .NET Core. Libraries written to a .NET Standard can potentially be consumed by both .NET Framework and .NET Core applications, and I believe you could also include separate executables in an extension and run them as separate processes if there's some piece that absolutely must run in a .NET Core environment, but you can't mix-and-match within a single process, and the extension code itself doesn't get a choice: it runs in the Visual Studio process.