# Register custom check-in policies in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, policies

In Visual Studio 2017 to register custom check-in policies i would use privateregistry.bin located in %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15_..., and i would add keys to the following path:

\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15......\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies

i know that in 2019 The registry path is 16.... something.

i´ve checked the .bin file and there is an entry with the policie but it doesn't load our custom check-in policies in VS.

i´ve also checked the registry entry and there is no new entry for visual studio 2019.

i hope somebody can help me.

Comment: I'm a little suprised the registry thing still worked for you in VS2017. It didn't for me (only in 2015). So I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923272/custom-tfs-check-in-policy-in-visual-studio-2017) and received a good answer. Maybe it helps you, too.

Comment: I've already tried this solution. The vsix installation worked fine, but after that my custom policy is still not available.