# How to add/modify private registry keys for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, registry, vs-extensibility

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933610/811785), I added keys to Visual Studio 2017 and it worked just fine. But it doesn't work for Visual Studio 2019.

Here's what I do:

1. I create a new project, using VSIX project template
2. I add a `.pkgdef` file to it, and I populate it using these lines:
   `[$RootKey$\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]
   "ExampleKey"="ExampleValue"`
3. I modify `source.extension.vsixmanifest` file and add assemblies and packages to it (based on that answer, and just like VS2017)
4. I make sure my extension is unsintalled (VS2019 => Extension => Manage Extensions => Selecting my extension => Uninstall => Closing VS2019)
5. Then I make sure the `ExampleKey    ExampleValue` is not present in `privateregistry.bin`. (Opening `regedit.exe`, selecting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` => File => Load hive => `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_e880ebae\privateregistry.bin` as VS2019Registry, then selecting `VS2019Registry\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_e880ebae_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies`)
6. Then I unload the `VS2019Registry` hive.
7. Then I double click my extension, and install it on VS2019
8. Then I open VS2019 to make sure my extension is installed, and it's in the list of extensions.
9. Then I close VS2019, and reopen private registry, but my key is not added to the intended path.

What should I do? How can I debug it? The exact same path was working for VS2017.

Comment: Why not just manually add your keys in step 5?

Comment: Because that's counterproductive for a large software team, with fully automated QA infrastructure.

Comment: I've done this before with a .pkgdef. How exactly did you edit the .vsixmanifest to include the .pkgdef file?

With similar entries in my TFSPolicies.pgkdef file, I added the following <asset> tag to my .vsixmanifest to include the .pkgdef as an asset:

    <Assets>
        <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="File" Path="TFSPolicies.pkgdef" />

    </Assets>